# Output text file isn't displaying data properly

Tags: python

I am writing a code that is supposed to take a user input of a range of numbers then read the text file, which contains the names of the first 44 US Presidents in order.  Then the code should display the names of the presidents that are within the range to an output file. What I have so far is the following:

```html
def main():
    """
    Display a range of presidents
    """
    lowerNumber, upperNumber = getRange()
    displayPresidents(lowerNumber, upperNumber)

def getRange():
    """
    Get range from user input
    """
    lowerNumber = int(input('Enter the lower number for the range: '))
    upperNumber = int(input('Enter the upper number for the range: '))
    return lowerNumber, upperNumber

def displayPresidents(lowerNumber, upperNumber):
    """
    Read from USPres.txt and print only the presidents that are within the given
    lower and upperNumber  provided ,write the output
    to an output file name as output.txt
    You can not use a list to solve this problem
    """
    output_file = open('Output.txt', 'w')
    with open('USPres.txt') as file:
        for line_num, content in enumerate(file, 1):
            content = content.rstrip('\n')
            if line_num in range(lowerNumber, upperNumber+1):
                desired_content = str(line_num) + " " + content
                output_file.write(desired_content)
                print(output_file)
    file.close()
    output_file.close()

main()
```

When I run the program it displays this:

```html
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Output.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Output.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Output.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Output.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Output.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

However, the code should be saying

```html
10 John Tyler 
11 James Polk 
12 Zachary Taylor
13 Millard Fillmore
14 Franklin Pierce
```

The code prints the correct results when I don't add in the code for writing it to the file.  Any advice or suggestions you can offer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `print(output_file)`  --> `print(desired_content)`

Comment: It looks like your output file should be showing the correct text. Is it just what's printing to the console that's incorrect?

Comment: *The code prints the correct results when I don't add in the code for writing it to the file* no, it doesn't. It doesn't `print` anything if you omit that code. Check the contents of your file. You should find that the file contains the correct information, and only that your `print` statement is incorrect as Johnny mentions above.

Comment: `output_file` is a file object that you created using `open()`, you are just ranting the wrong thing.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r: Yes.  I just added print(output_file) to check that the information I'm writing to the text file is correct.  How do I view the output file?

Comment: you print its *contents*, which you've assigned via the `desired_content` object, as @JohnnyMopp mentioned in the first comment, above. Alternatively, open the file in read mode & read its contents directly. Or, just *open the damn file* in Notepad.exe and view its contents! But in any case you don't use `print` against the `file object` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Johnny Mopp has the code change that you need to make to see the correct information printed out to the console.

You're creating your output file in same directory that you're running your script. So, after running your script, say:

```
python my_script.py
```

Type

```
cat Output.txt
```

To see the contents of your file.